# XamarinForms - Unable to resolve interface type Android - after upgrading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I have just upgraded Visual Studio for Mac and I am now getting an error when trying to build the Android project.

Any ideas which Assembly reference / package I need to add?

....D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ShellItemRenderer.cs(0,0): Error XA4204: Unable to resolve interface type 'Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationBarView/IOnItemSelectedListener'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (XA4204) (Android)

....D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\TabbedPageRenderer.cs(0,0): Error XA4204: Unable to resolve interface type 'Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationBarView/IOnItemSelectedListener'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (XA4204) (Android)

I've got Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2244 package installed

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.14 (build 17)

Xamarin.Android
Version: 12.0.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-11/f0e3c2d
Android SDK: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
6.0 (API level 23)
7.1 (API level 25)
8.0 (API level 26)
8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 30.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.3

Answer (score 2):

This refers to nuget Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.

A newer version is required for XF 5.0.0.xxxx

Manage nugets for solution - add it or update it.